# Replace unicode number between to different delimiters with NCHAR function

Tags: sql-server

I've created a MSSQL Server function which encodes special chars (example: हिन्दीabcde fG#) to the unicode number with "#" and ";" as delimiter. Only very simple chars like "abc" will not be encoded:

```
declare @position int, @txt nvarchar(max), @output as varchar(max);
set @position=1;
set @txt = N'हिन्दीabcde fG#';
set @output = '';

while @position <= len(@txt)
begin

    declare @t int;
    select @t=unicode(substring(@txt,@position,1))
    --print '&#'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(5),@t)+';'
    if ( (@t between 48 and 57) OR (@t between  65 and 90) or (@t between 97 and 122) )
    BEGIN
    SET @output = @output +  CONVERT(nvarchar(5), substring(@txt,@position,1) );    
    END
    else
    BEGIN
        SET @output = @output + '#'+ CONVERT(nvarchar(5),@t)+';'    
    END
    set @position = @position+1
end


Print @output
```

The result is:

```
2361;#2367;#2344;#2381;#2342;#2368;abcde#32;fG#35;
```

I need it for working with ODBC drivers and to avoid problems with special chars.

But now I need the way back - to decode the encoded chars. Is there any smart solution or will I need at least two loops, the "NCHAR" function ...?

I'll try to build such a function - if it's successfull, I'll post it here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this approach a little more appealing. First, create a split function that maintains order:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStringsOrdered
(
  @List   NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @delim  NVARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
  (
      SELECT rn, v = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, rn,
        CHARINDEX(@delim, @List + @delim, rn) - rn)))
      FROM
      (
        SELECT TOP (8000) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
      ) AS n 
      WHERE rn <= LEN(@List)
      AND SUBSTRING(@delim + @List, rn, LEN(@delim)) = @delim
  );
GO
```

Usage:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'#2361;#2367;#2344;#2381;'
                      + N'#2342;#2368;abcde#32;fG#35;';


-- need one small adjustment to make the string more split-friendly:
SET @x = REPLACE(@x, '#', ';#');

DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @output = (SELECT
  CASE WHEN v LIKE '#%' THEN NCHAR(REPLACE(v, '#', '')) ELSE v END 
  FROM dbo.SplitStringsOrdered(@x, ';') AS x
  ORDER BY rn FOR XML PATH(''), 
  TYPE).value('./text()[1]','nvarchar(max)');

SELECT @output;
```

Output:

```
हिन्दीabcde fG#
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with this query:

```
declare @position int, @txt nvarchar(max), @output as nvarchar(max), @buffer as varchar(max);
set @position=1;
set @txt = '#2361;#2367;#2344;#2381;#2342;#2368;abcde#32;fG#35;';
set @output = '';
set @buffer = '';

while @position <= len(@txt)
begin

    declare @t varchar(max);
    select @t=(substring(@txt,@position,1))



    if ( len(@buffer) = 0 and  @t <> '#' and  @t <> ';')
    BEGIN
        -- Append simple chars, which were not encoded
        Print 'Hänge den String ganz normal an den Output: ' + @t
        SET @output = @output + @t;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        if ( @t = '#' )
        BEGIN
            Print 'Raute wurde erkannt: #';
            SET @buffer = '#';
        END
        else if ( @t = ';' )
        BEGIN
            SET @buffer = REPLACE( @buffer, '#' , '' );
            Print 'Umwandeln: ' + @buffer
            SET @output = @output + isnull( NCHAR(@buffer) , '');
            SET @buffer = '';
        END
        else
        BEGIN
            Print 'Ganzzahl an den Buffer anhängen: ' + @t;
            SET @buffer = @buffer +  @t;
        END
    END

    set @position = @position+1
end


Print @output
```